# What steps are needed for fully homomorphic encryption?

Tags: algorithm-design, implementation

In my project work, I want to encrypt the keywords extracted from certain documents by using fully homomorphic encryption.
What are the algorithmic steps to perform fully homomorphic encryption on plaintext?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why is fully homomorphic encryption required?

Comment: You really want a description of how FHE works step-by-step, with enough details to implement the algorithm? Because you know, that's highly non-trivial...

Comment: My project work is that the user can retrieve files from cloud that are encrypted stored by data owner by using multiple keywords. So this encryption method is required to encrypt the keywords extracted from the files and the multi-keywords requested by the user, then perform the search operation over these encrypted indexes and the requested keywords. Can you plz help me..

Comment: If your question is about how to implement FHE step-by-step, no, no one can help you. This is a highly complex subject, one that requires study and dedication, not just something one can answer with a few lines on a stackexchange website. Even more, I would say that if you are not already very confident with advanced cryptographic implementations, you should give up on trying to implement it, and look for existing implementations instead, such as HElib.

Comment: sir, Can you suggest any other technique instead of fully homomorphic encryption?

Comment: Your question is too broad. I suggest you do some research in the literature to see what techniques are out there, then get back to us. One paper I highly recommend you start with is [this one](https://oaklandsok.github.io/papers/fuller2017.pdf).